# What does the word "rolling" mean in a rpm package version context?

Tags: centos, rhel, yum, rpm

What does the word "**rolling**" in "*1:13.0.1.9-2.rolling.el7*" below signify?

```
=================================================================================================
 Package                            Arch         Version                        Repository  Size
=================================================================================================
Installing:
 java-latest-openjdk                x86_64       1:13.0.1.9-2.rolling.el7       epel       207 k
Installing for dependencies:
 java-latest-openjdk-headless       x86_64       1:13.0.1.9-2.rolling.el7       epel        40 M

Transaction Summary
=================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.rolling` was added to the OpenJDK release number in Fedora, RHEL, and descendants to avoid file conflicts with the versioned OpenJDK packages (`java-11-openjdk` etc.). The `latest` package sometimes matches a versioned OpenJDK package, and when that happens, both packages ship files in the same locations; adding `.rolling` to the `latest` package’s release avoids this.

See [#1647298](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1647298) for details.

One possible meaning for “rolling” here is that it’s a continuously-updated package, which might change major versions within a release of the distribution.

Answer (score 0):

**nothing** or **anything**.

This package has the version number `13.0.1.9-2.rolling.el7` but that might as well have been `13.0.1.9-2.rolling-stones.el7` or whatever. For `rpm` this is just **text**.

Comment: I assume someone chose to add the word *rolling* to for a reason, it's that reason I'm looking for.